# asp.net mvc when should i read servervariables?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, request.servervariables

When is the apropriate time (part of code) that i can gather information from servervariables? I mean, i have tried calling this

```
string temp = Request.ServerVariables.Get("HTTP_REMOTE_USER");
```

in the Controller constructor, but i am getting a nullpointerexception, while in an action it works properly. And it just doesnt seem very clean to call it in each action..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could define a property in your controller or Base Controller:

```
protected string HttpRemoteUser
{
    get
    {
        return Request.ServerVariables.Get("HTTP_REMOTE_USER");
    }
}
```

And then call this property in your actions instead of Request.ServerVariables.Get

Answer (score 0):

Request.ServerVariables.Get("HTTP_REMOTE_USER") won't help in .net core mvc straight away. You should read server variables when for example:

```
ip = Request.HttpContext.GetServerVariable("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR");
ip = Request.HttpContext.GetServerVariable("REMOTE_ADDR");
```

See also: [Access HttpContext in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-7.0)