# How to mock the Request.ServerVariables using MOQ for ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, moq

i'm just learning to put in unit testing for my asp.net mvc when i came to learn about the mock and the different frameworks there is out there now.

after checking SO, i found that MOQ seems to be the easiest to pick up.
as of now i'm stuck trying to mock the Request.ServerVariables, as [after reading this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/975276/asp-net-mvc-when-should-i-read-servervariables), i've learned that it's better to abstract them into property.

as such:

```
/// <summary>
        /// Return the server port
        /// </summary>
        protected string ServerPort
        {
            get
            {
                return Request.ServerVariables.Get("SERVER_PORT");
            }
        }
```

But i'm having a hard time learning how to properly mock this.
I have a home controller ActionResult function which grabs the user server information and proceed to create a form to grab the user's information.

i tried to use [hanselman's mvcmockhelpers class](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETMVCSessionAtMix08TDDAndMvcMockHelpers.aspx) but i'm not sure how to use it.

this is what i have so far...

```
[Test]
        public void Create_Redirects_To_ProductAdded_On_Success() 
        {

            FakeViewEngine engine = new FakeViewEngine();

            HomeController controller = new HomeController();
            controller.ViewEngine = engine;

            MvcMockHelpers.SetFakeControllerContext(controller);

            controller.Create();

            var results = controller.Create();

            var typedResults = results as RedirectToRouteResult;

            Assert.AreEqual("", typedResults.RouteValues["action"], "Wrong action");
            Assert.AreEqual("", typedResults.RouteValues["controller"], "Wrong controller");
        }
```

### Questions:

1. As of now i'm still getting null
   exception error when i'm running the
   test. So what am i missing here?
2. And if i use the mvcmockhelpers
   class, how can i still call the
   request.verifyall function to ensure
   all the mocking are properly setup?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

so basically i've put in all the references and using this function i was able to get it working. i didn't use mvcmockhelpers class yet as i'm still trying to learn all of this.

and for anyone who's interested to see how i solved this, this is the code that i used.

```
[Test]
public void Create_Returns_ViewResult_On_Success() 
{
  var server = new Mock<HttpServerUtilityBase>(MockBehavior.Loose);
  var response = new Mock<HttpResponseBase>(MockBehavior.Strict);

  var request = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>(MockBehavior.Strict);
  request.Setup(x => x.ApplicationPath).Returns("/");
  request.Setup(x => x.Url).Returns(new Uri("http://localhost"));
  request.Setup(x => x.ServerVariables).Returns(new System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection{
    { "SERVER_NAME", "localhost" },
    { "SCRIPT_NAME", "localhost" },
    { "SERVER_PORT", "80" },
    { "HTTPS", "www.melaos.com" },
    { "REMOTE_ADDR", "127.0.0.1" },
    { "REMOTE_HOST", "127.0.0.1" }
  });

  var context = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
  context.SetupGet(x => x.Request).Returns(request.Object);
  context.SetupGet(x => x.Response).Returns(response.Object);
  context.SetupGet(x => x.Server).Returns(server.Object);

  var controller = new HomeController();
  //MvcMockHelpers.SetFakeControllerContext(controller);
  controller.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext(context. Object, new RouteData(), controller);

  var results = controller.Create();
  Assert.IsNotNull(results);
  Assert.IsInstanceOf(typeof(ViewResult), results);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I want to mock HttpContext, not HttpContextBase, I tried to find a way to convert HttpContextBase mock object to HttpContext and found out that it's impossible to do.

> **HttpContext**
>
> This is the vintage asp.net context. The problem with this is that it
>   has no base class and isn't virtual, and hence is unusable for testing
>   (cannot mock it). It's recommended to not pass it around as function
>   arguments, instead pass around variables of type HttpContextBase.
>
> **HttpContextBase**
>
> This is the (new to c# 3.5) replacement to HttpContext. Since it is
>   abstract, it is now mockable. The idea is that your functions that
>   expect to be passed a context should expect to receive one of these.
>   It is concretely implemented by HttpContextWrapper
>
> **HttpContextWrapper**
>
> Also new in C# 3.5 - this is the concrete implementation of
>   HttpContextBase. To create one of these in a normal webpage, use new
>   HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current).
>
> The idea is that to make your code unit-testable, you declare all your
>   variables and function parameters to be of type HttpContextBase, and
>   use an IOC framework eg Castle Windsor to get it injected. In normal
>   code, castle is to inject the equivalent of 'new
>   HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current)', whereas in test code you're
>   to be given a mock of HttpContextBase.
>
> (source: http://www.splinter.com.au/httpcontext-vs-httpcontextbase-vs-httpcontext/)

So I change the way to call my code.

From using `HttpContext`:

```
public static string GetIpAddress(HttpContext currentContext) {
 ...
}
```

To use `HttpContextBase`:

```
public static string GetIpAddress(HttpContextBase currentContext) {
 ...
}
```

And when I use the method, I wrap **HttpContext** with **HttpContextWrapper** like so:

```
var ip = GeneralUtil.GetIpAddress(new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current));
```

Now you can easily mock **HttpContextBase** by following [Dan Atkinson's reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2771333/1868276)