# Get header values in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http-headers

I have a requirement to capture the HTTP User Agent header coming in from a device, take the value and remove a *'uuid'* This UUID can then be used to direct the device to the correct location to give it the files relevant to the device.

In webforms I was able to get it using

```
Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]; //inside of Page_Load method
```

How would I go about this in MVC?

Answer (score 30):

if in controller, you can easily get the header by this:

```
Request.Headers.GetValues("XXX");
```

if the name does not exist, it will throw an exception.

Comment: what type of exception?

Comment: @Zapnologica InvalidOperationException

Comment: For .Net Core 6, use `TryGetValue` instead.

Answer (score 15):

You do it the same way, in the controller:

```
Request.ServerVariables.Get("HTTP_USER_AGENT");
```

The `Request` object is part of ASP.NET, MVC or not.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/975276/asp-net-mvc-when-should-i-read-servervariables) for example.

Answer (score 6):

It should be in the `Request.Headers` dictionary.

Answer (score 5):

**.Net 6 and above, this is how it works:**

```
Request.Headers.TryGetValue("Auth-Token", out StringValues headerValues);
string jsonWebToken = headerValues.FirstOrDefault();
```

I prefer the new syntax which is more concise:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetAuth([FromHeader(Name = "Auth-Token")] string jwt) {
```

Headers without hypens **-**'s don't need the Name, they map automagically:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetAuth([FromHeader]string host) {
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is anyone like me, who Googled to see how to get the `Content-Type` HTTP request header specifically, it's fairly easy:

```
Request.ContentType
```

Answer (score 0):

With Core 3.1 and Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor 3.1, you can:

```
string sid = Request.Headers["SID"];
```

For whatever header variable you are looking for.  Returns NULL if not found.

Answer (score 0):

To be on the safe side in terms of exception throws while the key doesn't exist in the header.

```
const string HeaderKeyName = "HeaderKey";
bool isValueExist = Request.Headers.TryGetValues(HeaderKeyName, out var values);
```

if isValueExist true then you should get arrays of values